# Get current time in HH:MM format

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor

How to get the current time and send it in `HH:MM` format in a field to schedule an event at the current time using Protractor?

Answer (score 3):

I was automating some of my test cases and I got one requirement where I have to validate some record with date and time. In this case I captured date and time and verified respectively.

Step which I have taken

1- Decide which date format you want, then we can use SimpleDateFormat class to do the same. I took below format

SimpleDateFormat(“MM/dd/yyyy”)

2- Create Date class object which will return Date and time

3- Then using format method get the date and time.

**Program 1- Write a program which will capture System Date**

```
package demo;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class GetDateinJava {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 // Create object of SimpleDateFormat class and decide the format
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy ");

 //get current date time with Date()
 Date date = new Date();

 // Now format the date
 String date1= dateFormat.format(date);

 // Print the Date
 System.out.println(date1);

 }

}
```

**OUTPUT**
http://www.cev.washington.edu/lc/CLWEBCLB/jst/js_datetime.html

**Program 2- Write a program which will capture System Date/ Time**

In this example I am taking time as well so I have added HH:MM:SS also in format

package demo;

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class GetDateinJava {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 // Create object of SimpleDateFormat class and decide the format
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

 //get current date time with Date()
 Date date = new Date();

 // Now format the date
 String date1= dateFormat.format(date);

 // Print the Date
 System.out.println("Current date and time is " +date1);

 }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And, also you can refer the [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.cev.washington.edu/lc/CLWEBCLB/jst/js_datetime.html) page.

Comment: This is in Java , not in Protractor/JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the protractor.It is plain javascript thing..

```
var time = new Date();
console.log(time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes();
```